# открыть файл Excel на чтение c#

Tags: c#, excel

Задача забирать данные из файла Excel

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
class Program
{
    private static string NameExcel = @"\Список телефонов.xlsx";

    static void Main()
    { //Создаём приложение.
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ObjExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        //Открываем книгу.                                                                                                                                                        
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open(NameExcel, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
        //Выбираем таблицу(лист).
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;
        ObjWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[1];
        string [,] Telephons = new string[100];
        //Выбираем первые сто записей из столбца.
        for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
        {
            //Выбираем область таблицы. (в нашем случае просто ячейку)
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = ObjWorkSheet.get_Range("F" + i.ToString(), "F" + i.ToString());               
            //Добавляем полученный из ячейки текст.
            Telephons[i - 1] = range.Text.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что постоянно открывает файл на запись. Как его открыть только на чтение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите документацию [Workbooks.Open()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx).

Там третий параметр называется **ReadOnly**

Значит вам надо писать `ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open(NameExcel, 0, true, ...`

Answer (score 3):

Надо исправить `WorkBook.Open()`. 3 параметер `ReadOnly`

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open(NameExcel, 0, true, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
```

> Workbook Open(
>     string Filename,
>     Object UpdateLinks,
>     Object ReadOnly, 
>     Object Format,
>     Object Password,
>     Object WriteResPassword,
>     Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended,
>     Object Origin,
>     Object Delimiter,
>     Object Editable,
>     Object Notify,
>     Object Converter,
>     Object AddToMru,
>     Object Local,
>     Object CorruptLoad
>
> )

[WorkBook.Open()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open.aspx)